# Expression for "is x greater than y and less than z"?

Tags: javascript, syntax, comparison-operators

I'm trying to test if a number is greater than 0 but less than 8. How do I do that in JavaScript?

This is what I'm trying:

```
if (score > 0 < 8) { alert(score); }
```

Comment: @ephemient can you explain it please how your code works?

Comment: @tom Simple. `score>>>0` converts `score` to a non-negative integer. (Negatives become very large positive values due to two's complement representation.) If it is 8 or larger, `min` produces 8, bitwise and'ed with 7 to 0, a falsy value. If it is between 0 and 7, `min` changes nothing and neither does `&`, resulting in a falsy value of 0 or a truthy value between 1 and 7.

Comment: @AlexejMagura Chained inequality notation has been in use in mathematics for centuries. How's that for tradition? (e.g., Paolo Ruffini's General Theory of Equations, 1799, p. 82)

Comment: A related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6967573/1662230

Comment: A tangential question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4090845/1662230

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Here's the code:

```
if (score > 0 && score < 8){
    alert(score);
}
```

P.S. This has nothing to do with jQuery. It's simple, *naked* JavaScript!

Comment: We totally should be able to do something like:

if (8 > score > 0) {
   alert(score);
}

Comment: truly simple and nak$d javascript :)

Answer (score 2):

```
if ((score > 0) && (score < 8)) {
    alert(score);
}
```

But this is JavaScript, not jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Query: Create a variable named  score and set it to  8

Use `console.log()` that includes the string "Mid-level skills:" and compares the score variable to above 0 and below 10 using the && operator

Output :

```js
var score = 8;
console.log("Mid-level skills:", score > 0 && score < 10)
```