# Concise way to compare against multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the following:

```
var a = 'jesus';

if(a == 'something' || a == 'nothing' || a=='anything' || a=='everything'){
   alert('Who cares?');
}
```

Is there a way to make this shorter?

Is there anything in Javascript like `if (a=='bbb'||'ccc')`?

In addition, can jQuery help here?

Comment: The title of the question also invokes this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6967573/1662230

Answer (score 31, accepted):

With a regex:

```
if (/^(something|nothing|anything|everything)$/.exec('jesus')) alert('Who cares?');​
```

Or the opposite:

```
/^(something|nothing|anything|everything)$/.exec('jesus')||alert('Who cares?');​
```

[Update] Even shorter ;-)

```
if (/^(some|no|any|every)thing$/.exec('jesus')) alert('Who cares?');​
```

Comment: And contrary to array.indexOf my solution works for browsers BC (Before Chrome)

Comment: regex is 5 times slower see the test https://runkit.com/pramendra/58cad911146c1c00147f8d8d

Comment: Use [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) instead of [`exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) for faster execution. `test` will return only true or false, `exec` returns an array of results.

Answer (score 60):

You could use this...

```
if (["something", "nothing", "anything", "everything"].includes(a)) {
   alert('Who cares?');
}
```

If you're stuck with older browser support...

```
if (["something", "nothing", "anything", "everything"].indexOf(a) > -1) {
   alert('Who cares?');
}
```

You also tagged it jQuery, so if you need to support older browsers without `Array.prototype.indexOf()`, you could use [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/).

Answer (score 18):

You can put the options in array and use jQuery [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) or javascrpt [`indexOf()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp) to search array

**Pure javascript**

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/hn8XF/3/)**

```
var a = 'anything';
arr = ['something', 'nothing', 'anything', 'everything'];
if(arr.indexOf(a) != -1)
    alert("condition met");    
else
    alert("condition not met");
```

**With jQuery**

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/n5n9P/1/)**

```
var a = 'jesus';
arr = ['something', 'nothing', 'anything', 'everything'];

if($.inArray(a, arr) != -1) // With jQuery
    alert("condition met");    
else
    alert("condition not met");
```

Answer (score 10):

With ES7 you are able to use [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and even shorter notation than indexOf, which is already implemented in every modern browser.

Here is the example usage:

```
if (['hero', 'anything', 'everything'].includes(me)) {
    alert('Who cares?');
}
```

And the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Polyfill) from Mozilla.

Comment: You can use this as long as you don't consider IE to be a modern browser: [Array.prototype.includes() Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: IE is already 4-year-old. And like I said, there's a polyfill for that and you can even use Babel for creating builds for some older platforms.

Comment: Understood. My point was a joke about IE. I upvoted this since it is the best and most current answer for modern JS.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

If you want to check the words other than **Jesus**,
try following,

```
if(a != "jesus"){
   alert('Who cares?');
}
```

if you want to check particular words,
try following,

```
var check_arrays = ['something','nothing', 'anything', 'everything'];
if(checkThis(a)){
   alert('Who cares?');
}

function checkThis(a)
{
   for(i=0;i<check_arrays.length;i++)
   {
      if(check_arrays[i] == a)
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

May be using switch instead of if:

```
var a = 'jesus';
switch (a){
    case 'something':
    case 'nothing' :
    case 'anything':
    case 'everything':
   alert('Who cares?');
   break;
}
```

Comment: So long as you don't adhere to Crockford's *Good Parts* :)

Comment: I'm not sure that that's appreciably shorter, though it would be if testing a variable with a longer name.

Answer (score 2):

Using an object literal:

```
var all={something:1,nothing:1,anything:1,everything:1};
if (all.hasOwnProperty('jesus')) alert('Who cares?');​
```

I'd say this is the most concise cross-browser expression for general use (well, as long as the objective is to compare strings). It is also very flexible as you can easily add or remove properties:

```
all.mything=1;
delete all.nothing;
```

Comment: So long as no one does `Object.prototype.jesus = "lol";`. You could use `Object.create()` for an object without this behaviour.

Comment: @alex true. That said I wouldn't expect people to directly extend Object.prototype in practice. Am I right?

Comment: It is rare in practice. But you could swap the `in` operator for the `hasOwnProperty()` and then it becomes a non-issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no easy method to do this. But you can write a function `in_array` and you can use it anywhere you need

```
Array.prototype.in_array = function(p_val) {
    for(var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {
        if(this[i] == p_val) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var v_array = [ 'something','nothing', 'anything', 'everything'];

var a = "jesus";

if(v_array.in_array(a)){
    alert('Who cares?');
}
```

Comment: You're probably better off just shimming `Array.prototoype.indexOf()`.