# What is a better way of testing if a string doesn't equal a bunch of stuff?

Tags: javascript

right now I have:

```
if (breadCrumbArr[x] !== 'NEBC' && breadCrumbArr[x] !== 'station:|slot:' &&  breadCrumbArr[x] !== 'slot:' &&  breadCrumbArr[x] !== 'believe') {
    // more code
}
```

But I think this could be done better...

Comment: some answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13737091/concise-way-to-compare-against-multiple-values

Comment: most upvotes i ever got for a question i thought was gonna get downvoted

Comment: upvotes work in mysterious ways...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make an array and use `indexOf`:

```
['NEBC', 'station:|slot:', 'slot:', 'believe'].indexOf(breadCrumbArr[x]) === -1
```

Comment: +1 - and ignore IE 8-.

Comment: Alternately, you could use JQuery's `$.inArray(string_name, array_name)`, if that's an option.

Comment: @JimmiTh Don't need to ignore it. Just [include a polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility).

Comment: wow 8 upvotes in like 2 minutes

Comment: I should point out that `.indexOf()` does not give the same result as `!==` so this is not functionally equivalent to the OP's original code.

Comment: @jfriend00 Can you give an example?

Comment: @jfriend00 - in what way doesn't it? `.indexOf()` performs the comparison using strict equality, same as `===`, and in this case it will stop checking on the first match - same way as a chained `!==` (although in other cases, such as if the compared values were results of function calls, it obviously would evaluate all, rather than short circuit).

Comment: @jfriend00 thats chill, i would probably always use != instead of !== if people didn't think it was odd.

Answer (score 7):

You could use a `switch` statement:

```
switch(inputString){
  case "ignoreme1":
  case "ignoreme2":
  case "ignoreme3":
    break;
  default: 
    //Do your stuff
    break;
}
```

Comment: +1 for readability of this solution

Comment: @JonathanM how about -1 for the lack of flexibility, as values are hardcoded?

Comment: @JonathanM I agree that the hardcoded values is bad.. but that was the approach taken by the question, hence that's how I addressed it.

Comment: Sorry for the bad tag - the last comment was meant for @Christophe

Comment: @Christophe, I'm trying to understand what you mean. Can you give an example that doesn't involve hardcoding values?

Comment: @JonathanM see the other answers. If you store the values in an array or an object, then you can write code that adds/removes/updates the values. If you have the values in a case statement you cannot change them at runtime. (and for the record I was not serious about the downvote!)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Blender's answer: if you want to go cross browser, you could also use an object instead of an array:

```
var words = {
    'NEBC': true, 
    'station:|slot:': true, 
    'slot:': true, 
    'believe': true
};

if (!words[breadCrumbArr[x]]){
    //do stuff
}
```

It's also faster but it's also definitly uglier since you have to assign a value (in this case `true`) to every string that is used as property name.