# Tip to opimize a simple regex

Tags: regex

Let's say that I have the following words that I want to accept in a regular expression.
`iare, sare, are, snore , zere, tnore`

I could use the `or` expression going this way : `(iare|sare|are|snore|zere|tnore)`
but trying to optimize it, I rewrote it as following : `(s|t)?(t|n)?(i|s|a|z|t)?(a|o|e)re`

Is there a way to write a better regex than the last one?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Which regular expression engine are you using?

Comment: Against what criteria are you trying to optimize it? Performance? Readability? Portability?

Comment: @hwnd one character shorter `([is]?a|[st]no|ze)re` :P

Comment: The latter one would match `stsore` as well. In case you don't want that, the first one is better.

Comment: I'm not using any engine, just learning how to use regex for the moment. I'm using regexpal.com to test my rexpression.  My criteria to optimise it would be more the readability.

Comment: @user3054950 if it's readability, then just stick with your first expression. When it get's complicated, you might use the [`x` modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%2fx) to add space and comments.

Comment: Thanks HamZa, you're 2 answers are much appreciated.

Comment: @user3054950 See [this small demo](http://regex101.com/r/nA6sP7). Learn regex the [normal way](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) and the [easy way](http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/book/). You might even [play](http://regexcrossword.com) a bit or [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25767/regex) about it :)

Comment: @wmehanna if your objective is "more the readability", the answer is obvious just from reading your question!

Comment: @Christophe I noticed that when I read myself after posting it.  I guess now i'm more looking into performance.

Comment: @wmehanna for performance, the best option is often to... avoid using regex! For example, see here some alternate options in JavaScript (upvoted answers) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13737091/concise-way-to-compare-against-multiple-values/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two possible optimizations that will match the same as your expression:

`(?:ze|[is]?a|[st]no)re`

and

`(?:s(?:no|a)|i?a|tno|ze)re)`

Comment: i already got my answer long time ago but you'r regex makes a lot of senses.  Kudos to you! ;-)