# Operator in javaScript

Tags: javascript

Can i use operators like:

```
"wo" == ("man" || "wo");
```

or

```
x = ("man" || "wo");
"wo" == x;
```

if not is there any other technique that I can use?

Purpose was to save the length of code with different values in condition.

```
if(orderSubType == (sdcConstants().orderSubType.UNBAR_0 || 
                    sdcConstants().orderSubType.UNBAR_00 || 
                    sdcConstants().orderSubType.UNBAR_OG) && 
                    item.source == sdcConstants().source.EXT && 
                    item.code == sdcConstants().CFSS.CFSS_VOICE_DUNNING){
       item.state = sdcConstants().servAction.DELETE;
}else{
       item.state = sdcConstants().servAction.NO_OPERATION;
}
```

Comment: as far as I know no, because `"man" || "wo"` means `if "man" is falsey, then "wo", else "man"`. For such a task you might want to either use ~.indexOf(element) in an array or .hasOwnProperty on an object that contains the properties you want to check.

Comment: format it as : `if("wo" == "man" || "wo" == "wo") { ... }`

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: Well, it's close to what I wanted.
This code does OR Operator. Is it applicable to AND Operator as well?
x = ["man", "wo"];
if (x.indexOf("wo") != -1) {
    alert('found');
}

Comment: @MuneebAli: well `x` cannot be two things at once, so I don't see the point of having an AND operator. Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13737091/concise-way-to-compare-against-multiple-values

Answer (score 1):

> Can i use operators like:
>
> ```
> "wo" == ("man" || "wo");
> ```

Not for what you want that to do, no.

> Purpose was to save the length of code with different values in condition...

The usual two approaches for dealing with testing against multiple values are `switch` or a map, but as your condition is a compound of different properties and different logic operators, it's not going to buy you much.

Here's an example with `switch` (and **yes**, in JavaScript, those `case` statements are correct, JavaScript is not limited to constants like Java or C):

```
switch (orderSubType) {
    case sdcConstants().orderSubType.UNBAR_0:
    case sdcConstants().orderSubType.UNBAR_00:
    case sdcConstants().orderSubType.UNBAR_OG:
        if (item.source == sdcConstants().source.EXT && item.code == sdcConstants().CFSS.CFSS_VOICE_DUNNING) {
            item.state = sdcConstants().servAction.DELETE;
            break;
        }
        //FALL THROUGH TO DEFAULT
    default:
        item.state = sdcConstants().servAction.NO_OPERATION;
        break;
}
```

You can see why I don't think it buys you anything over the `if` version in this particular case:

```
if (    (orderSubType == sdcConstants().orderSubType.UNBAR_0 ||
         orderSubType == sdcConstants().orderSubType.UNBAR_00 ||
         orderSubType == sdcConstants().orderSubType.UNBAR_OG
        )
        && item.source == sdcConstants().source.EXT
        && item.code == sdcConstants().CFSS.CFSS_VOICE_DUNNING
    ) {
    item.state = sdcConstants().servAction.DELETE;
} else {
    item.state = sdcConstants().servAction.NO_OPERATION;
}
```

Comment: Can't this be done in an inline ternary operator using an array and indexOf?

Comment: @briosheje: It can be done with `indexOf` as well, if you want to create an unnecessary array and make an unnecessary method call. You don't need a ternary if you do that.

Comment: That was for the "Purpose was to save the length of code with different values in condition..." point :P

Comment: @briosheje: Ah, yes, I see what you're thinking: `item.state = conditionsHere ? sdcConstants().servAction.DELETE : sdcConstants().servAction.NO_OPERATION;` At that point, with as many conditions as we have here, to my mind you're running into serious readability/debugging/maintenance issues.

Comment: exactly. something like that:  `item.state = (([sdcConstants().orderSubType.UNBAR_0, sdcConstants().orderSubType.UNBAR_00,sdcConstants().orderSubType.UNBAR_OG].indexOf(orderSubType) + 1) && item.source == sdcConstants().source.EXT
        && item.code == sdcConstants().CFSS.CFSS_VOICE_DUNNING ) ? sdcConstants().servAction.DELETE : sdcConstants().servAction.NO_OPERATION;` . It's terrible if you look at it, but it's still inline :P

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array and check if the item exists in the array. For example,

```
x = ["man", "wo"];
if (x.indexOf("wo") != -1) {
    alert('found');
}
```

Comment: The `in` operator only iterates over the [properties of the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in). This will not work.

Comment: I edited my answer. This works. Check this fiddle for its working: http://jsfiddle.net/14kjzmqh/