# Attaching an image to a randomly generated number between 1-10?

Tags: javascript, html, image, random

I'm fairly new to HTML and I'm able to successfully generate the random numbers, but I want to attach an image to a specific number E.G  a card game (11 =jack =12=queen ..etc)

This is what I have

```
function numbers() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    if(x ==1||2||3||4||5||6||7) {
        img.src = "ace.jpg";
    }
    document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = "Rule " + x;
}
```

Comment: `if(x == 1 || x == 2|| x == 3|| x == 4|| x == 5|| x == 6|| x == 7) {` This would do it, you have to check every single value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concise way to compare against multiple values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13737091/concise-way-to-compare-against-multiple-values)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [switch...case](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp). 
something like

```
switch(x) {
case 1:
    img.src = "king.jpg";
    break;
case 2:
    img.src = "queen.jpg"
    break;
...
default:
    img.src = "ace.jpg"
```

}

where the "..." is just replaced by more cases (how many you need).

the `default` case is run when no other cases match `x`.

If you were interested in why the `break` keyword is necessary, information about it can be found in the link i provided. basically

> When the JavaScript code interpreter reaches a break keyword, it
>   breaks out of the switch block.
>
> This will stop the execution of more code and case testing inside the
>   block.

meaning the whole `switch(x){...}` is a "block" where `x` is compared to each `case`. If there is a match, the code there is executed, but if theres nothing telling it to stop, it'll just keep running code! So the `break` keyword exits the whole block, keeping other cases from running!

Comment: this introduces the `break` keyword, which is hardly intuitive to someone just learning to program (especially combined with the "fall-through" behavior of a `switch`), but it is still the best way to solve this problem, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
imgArr = ['jack.png', 'queen.png','tree.png','man.png','ace.png','king.png','yellow.png','green.png','black.png','white.png'],
      randomNumber = 0,
      numImgMap = {}; // map between image and random number.

function randomNumberGenerator(){
 return Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
}

for(var k = 0; k < 10; k++ ){
   randomNumber = randomNumberGenerator();
   numImgMap[randomNumber] = imgArr[randomNumber];

} 
// numImgMap is now your map(object) with random number associated with random images.
```