# Checking string match with some other string (multiple condition in same line)

Tags: javascript

I am using below logic for checking particular string matching with other string or not

```
if (searchTxt == "All" || searchTxt == "WORD1" || searchTxt == 'WORD2' || searchTxt == 'WORD3' || searchTxt == 'WORD4' || searchTxt == 'WORD5') {
}
```

Above code is working fine but showing warning

> Reduce the number of conditional operators (5) used in the expression
>   (maximum allowed 3)

.

How to resolve this warning

Comment: Create an array of those words and use `if(array.includes(searchTxt)){...}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check variable equality against a list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728144/check-variable-equality-against-a-list-of-values) and [Javascript: The prettiest way to compare one value against multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121395) and [Concise way to compare against multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13737091)

Answer (score -1):

In this example, you'd be better off with a [switch statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch); If you want to do the same thing with multiple terms, such as "WORD1" and "WORD2", eliminate the break and put the code you want to do in the last of the matches.

```js
switch(searchTxt){
  case "All": 
    // do something
  case "WORD1": 
    // do something
  case "WORD2": 
    // do something
  case "WORD3": 
    // this switch case will do something for 
    // "WORD1", "WORD2", "WORD3", "All"
    break;
  case "WORD4":
    // do something
    break;
  case "WORD5":
    // do something
    break;
  default:
    // do something if no match
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Your code is currently needlessly repetitive.

How aout putting the acceptable options in an array then using a dynamic REGEX to test:

```
let allowed = ['foo', 'bar', 'etc'];
if (new RegExp('/^('+allowed.join('|')+')$/').test(searchTxt)) { alert('match'); }
```

Comment: Compare your code with something like ['foo', 'bar', 'etc'].indexOf(searchTxt) === -1 in terms of readability, performance and simplicity.

Comment: True - `indexOf()` or `includes()` is more readable, but I still answered the question and solved the OP's problem.