# React JavaScript How to optimize this if / or statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement

Do you have a better way to create this `if` / `elseif` sentence?

```js
 if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Opera') || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('OPR')) != -1) {
      this.state.isBrowserAllowed = true;
    } else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') != -1) {
      this.state.isBrowserAllowed = true;
    } else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1) {
      this.state.isBrowserAllowed = true;
    } else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') != -1) {
      this.state.isBrowserAllowed = true;
    }
```

Comment: You should not mutate the state directly. Use `this.setState`

Comment: Do you actually need to block other browsers (assuming that's what you're doing)?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of "Check variable equality against a list of values" - the userAgent is a long string which may contain certain browser substrings

Comment: Yes I'm trying to detect when user try to use my web on Instagram  or Xiomi, or other browser...

Comment: looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13737091/concise-way-to-compare-against-multiple-values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use a regular expression instead.

```
this.setState({
  ...this.state,
  isBrowserAllowed: /Opera|OPR|Chrome|Safari|Firefox/.test(navigator.userAgent)
});
```

Also, as the comment notes, state should not be mutated in React - use `setState` instead.