# Javascript if statement or operator not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
"use strict";

function vovelsAndConstants(s) {

  let vowels = new Array();
  let constants = new Array();

  for (let a = 0; a < s.length; a++) {
    //console.log(s[a]);
    if (s[a] === "a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u") {
      console.log(s[a]);
    }
  }
 
}

vovelsAndConstants("sosisvesalam");
```

I can't understand why or operator here doesn't work It all makes sense to me. It outputs all chars instead of vowels

Comment: `s[a] === "a" || "e"` ----> `s[a] === "a" || s[a] === "e"` ...

Comment: Use `includes`.

Comment: `if (s[a] === "a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u")` means `if((s[a] === "a") || Boolean("e") || Boolean("i") || Boolean("o") || Boolean("u"))` which is basically `if((s[a] === "a") || true || true || true || true)` or simply `if(true)`. Take a look at [Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Comment: off topic, but take a look at this: `let vowels = s.match(/[aeiou]/gi);` 
`let consonants = s.match(/[^aeiou]/gi);` or better `let consonants = s.match(/(?=[a-z])[^aeiou]/gi);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concise way to compare against multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13737091/concise-way-to-compare-against-multiple-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for equality for each case:

```js
function vovelsAndConstants(s) {
  const vowels = new Array();
  const constants = new Array();
  for (let a = 0; a < s.length; a++) {
    if (s[a] === "a" || s[a] === "e" || s[a] === "i" || s[a] === "o" || s[a] === "u") {
      console.log(s[a]);
    }
  }
}

vovelsAndConstants("sosisvesalam");
```

Another way using [`.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```js
const VOWEL_LETTERS = ["a","e","i","o","u"];

function vovelsAndConstants(s) {
  const vowels = new Array();
  const constants = new Array();
  for (let a = 0; a < s.length; a++) {
    if (VOWEL_LETTERS.indexOf(s[a]) !== -1) {
      console.log(s[a]);
    }
  }
}

vovelsAndConstants("sosisvesalam");
```

Answer (score 4):

IMO the easiest way is to use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), otherwise you will have to list all the different comparisons separately.

**Replace:**

`s[a] === "a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u"`

**with:**

`["a","e","i","o","u"].includes(s[a])`

**or** as [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6567275/thomas) suggested in his comment:

`"aeiou".includes(s[a])`

These will do a string comparison and not a type comparison as `===` would do but it could still work for you.

Comment: You don't need the array here *(overhead)*. You can use [String#includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) `"aeiou".includes(s[a])`

Comment: @Thomas true! I guess an array would be more practical for the OP. But nice addition, thanks !

Comment: IMHO, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense to you based on the language we speak, whereas with programming you have to be explicit.

```
if (s[a] === "a" || s[a] === "e" || s[a] === "i" || s[a] === "o" || s[a] === "u") {
   console.log(s[a]);
}
```

JavaScript doesn't know what you are comparing "e" or "i" or "o" to, you need to tell it every time.

Answer (score 1):

Your current condition only compare the *a* character successfully. From the second check all comparison segment is *true*, hence outputs all the characters.

You have to compare the currently iterated character with all possible vowels in the condition:

```js
"use strict";

function vovelsAndConstants(s) {

  let vowels = new Array();
  let constants = new Array();

  for (let a = 0; a < s.length; a++) {
    if (s[a] === "a" || s[a] ==="e" || s[a] ==="i" || s[a] ==="o" || s[a] ==="u") {
      console.log(s[a]);
    }
  }
 
}

vovelsAndConstants("sosisvesalam");
```